# Unable to call a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm learning mysql stored procedures and, as it turns out, I'm not so good at it for now. I want to create a stored procedure that selects some columns from different tables and, obviously, outputs the result. I have:

```
USE `usertable159`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `getDataFor`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `usertable159`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`michael`@`%` PROCEDURE `getDataFor`(IN COUNTRY VARCHAR(2), IN ASIN VARCHAR(20),IN FC VARCHAR(1))
BEGIN
      SET @sql = "select p.price, p.sku, p.fulfillment_channel, GROUP_CONCAT(es.excludedSeller) excluded, r.excludeNonFeatured 
      FROM "+COUNTRY+"_products p
      LEFT JOIN ("+COUNTRY+"_excludedSellers es, "+COUNTRY+"_excludeRules r)
      ON p.seller_sku = es.seller_sku and p.seller_sku = r.seller_sku where p.ASIN = '" + ASIN + "' and p.fulfillment_channel = " + FC + ";
"; 
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

From all the errors I expected when writing this... the one I get is surprising to me:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'de' in 'field list'

This is how I call it:

```
call getDataFor(de, B000LNHB8A, 2);
```

The IN parameter `COUNTRY` is not in the selected columns, how does it come?

I also tried calling it with

```
call getDataFor('de', 'B000LNHB8A', '2');
```

which results in

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1) You cannot concatenate strings with `+` in MySQL. You must use the `CONCAT()` built-in function.

2) Your `LEFT JOIN` syntax is incorrect. It should be `LEFT JOIN x ON ... LEFT JOIN y ON ...`.

3) You must quote your arguments. It looks like you also tried that. You definitely need to do that.

Comment: Thanks! It works with concat! The left join syntax actually is valid, too. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html.

Comment: My guess is that #1 is the reason for the error "near 2". MySQL is most likely casting each piece of that string to an int, and `FC` is the only piece that casts to something other than 0...meaning the query being executed is literally "2".

Comment: @baao: I was afraid it would be something like that. Another non-standard MySQL extension to confuse the world...

Comment: You mean the left join thing? That's true, I changed it to the syntax you recommended as I'm always using that way, too... Actually I wanted to try it as I saw it in the documentation...  Reading mysql's documentation reveals many non standard syntax... :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the call arguments:

```
call getDataFor('de', 'B000lNHB8A', 2)
                ^--^  ^----------^
```

Remember that any "string" that's not in quotes will be interpreted as a table/field name reference, NOT the value it represents.

Comment: sorry the edit was too late. I also tried this. It's the second error message. (Also tried with and without quotes around 2), actually this was my first try...